# Check if contact has photo on Android >2.3.3

Tags: android, sql, contacts, photo

I need to check via query,if a contact has a photo but all solutions found on stack didn´t work for me:

```
Cursor cur = this.ctx.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            null, ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"
                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null,
            null);
```

This is one which doesn´t work, because "database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column mimetype"

I also tried to check if the PHOTO_ID is 0, but this will never happen.

How can I do a query which filters contacts with/without photo?

EDIT:

Okay found a solution by trying. It seems to work with PHOTO_ID

```
String hasPhoto = ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID + " LIKE '%%'";
String hasNoPhoto = ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID + " IS NULL";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a rawQuery on the database, passing the ID of the contact to the method?

```
public String withPhoto(int id){
SQLiteDatabase database = new SQLiteDatabase();
String column = null;

database.open();
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT column FROM table/content_uri WHERE PHOTO_ID IS/IS NOT NULL AND CONTACT_ID = " + id)
if(!cursor.moveToFirst()){
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     column = cursor.getString(1)
   }
  cursor.close();

  return column;
}
```

**Edit**

I apologize, I assumed you had your own database. Here is a link to the [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html) Class, which has info on photos:

Source: Android Developer

Comment: but I think it wouldn´t change anything. The "official" column for checking if a photo is available does not exist (anymore)

Comment: What identifiers do you have to identify a photo? Is there a separate table you could join to?

Comment: I have PHOTO_ID,PHOTO_URI,PHOTO_FIELD_ID and PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI. I´m not yet fimiliar with the contact database on android, but as far as I now are the photo details in the same table as the contact itself